# Overwriting memory for label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Rather than using `.grid_forget` where the memory for the previous label is still occupied, and using `.destroy()` where I totally destroy that memory slot, is it possible to just overwrite the memory slot used for that label when I'm updating the label with new text?

Comment: Yes, this is documented. Research the `configure` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Label Text in Python TkInter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083050/update-label-text-in-python-tkinter)