# Is the function call to update a tkinter label after a button command was executed reason for unexpected behavior?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

first of all let me start off by saying I started coding around 6 weeks ago in self-study, so it is very likely, that the approach may still be a total mess.

I have a program running (fine for me) in cli, but I want to make it usable for people that faint, when they see plain white text on a black background which they have to operate without a mouse.

Besides my main window, which is running in the background I wanted to have a message window, which displays the information if all necessary files where selected. which is shown below.

```
files_to_open = {'File_1':'', 'File_2':'', 'File_3':''}

def selectfiles_window():
    global message_window
    message_window = Tk()

    ...

    content = Label(message_window, text=get_open_file_status_txt(), **txt_status_general)
    content.pack(side='top')
    button_select_file1 = Button(message_window,text = 'File 1',font = txt_general['font'],command = lambda:(
select_file_action(name='File 1', filetypename='Excel workbook', extension='*.xlsx'),
content.configure(text=get_open_file_status_txt())))
    button_select_file1(side='bottom')
    message_window.mainloop()

def select_file_action(name, filetypename, extension):
    global files_to_open
    files_to_open[name] = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = f'Select {name}', filetypes=[(filetypename, extension)])


def get_open_file_status_txt():
    global files_to_open
    message =f'''
    [File_1] is {"NOT SET" if (files_to_open["File_1"] == "") else "SET"}'''
    return message
```

I expected, that the text is updated after the filedialog was closed (which is partly working as expected).

Now what I don't understand: If I click the button to select File_1 and cancel it for the first time, the value for key File_1 is set to (). Any time after that, if I click the button to select File_1 and cancel it, the value for key File_1 is set to ''. If I select a file the path is saved correctly as value (also on the first attempt). If I cancel it is set again to ''.

Anybody an idea about why the value is set to () on the first cancel but afterwards runs as expected?

I would also be grateful for a different solution to update the text, if my approach is totally off.

Thank you and best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Label Text in Python TkInter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083050/update-label-text-in-python-tkinter)

Comment: I am aware that an update on the label needs a function call, which is included in my code. What I am trying to find out, if my function call is cause of the unexpected behavior or if there is a different way to submit this function call after the command of the button has been carried out.

Comment: Please rephrase: Which ***unexpected behavior ...***? Why ***"different way to submit..."***

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, that the function call was not the issue, rather that it is a (strange to me but maybe intended) behavior of filedialog.askopenfilename, which returns an empty tuple if cancel is selected on first call but an empty string on every further canceled calls.